# Is there a "go to last edit" shortcut in Qt-Creator?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator

In VS2017, there's a really nice shortcut called -> go to last edit (Ctrl+Shift+Backspace), which let you go to the last file and line that you modified.

Is there something similar in Qt-Creator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/106230/qt-creator-missing-shortcut-go-to-last-edit) is a post opened in Qt Forum asking for this feature.

The administrators told me that there was something partially done (Spring 2017), but the changeset wasn't merged at all because it didn't pass the internal Qt tests.

After discussing a little bit with the Qt Community, we managed to correct the changeset and introduced the feature, which will be available in the latest Qt version (5.15 IIRC) . [This](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt-creator/qt-creator/+/190374) is the main code task.

[image: Example]

Comment: Coming from Java/Intellij this was a shortcut I used very often. Good to see it's coming up, I'd almost consider installing the beta version.

Answer (score 2):

There is no exact Shortcut but it has some similar shortcuts

1. Find previous <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
2. Find previous occurrence of selected text <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
3. Previous open document in history <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

according to  – [Albert Hendriks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/838494/albert-hendriks)

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT_ARROW</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT_ARROW</kbd> are very useful here. It will get you to the last edit location quickly.

Comment: ALT+LEFT_ARROW (and ALT+RIGHT_ARROW) are very useful here. It will get you to the last edit location quickly.